# Use Java to get resource on diff computer

Tags: java, java-io

```
 private static final String FILE_PATH = "MessageCompare\\src\\main\\resources\\json\\test.json";` 

 File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())));`
```

In my computer, file.getAbsolutePath() return
D:\Dev\Tool\MessageCompare\MessageCompare\src\main\resources\json\test.json

In other computer, file.getAbsolutePath() return
D:\Dev\Tool\MessageCompare\src\main\resources\json\test.json

Why does absolute path of file return one more node than others' computer?

Comment: Check the folder structure on both of the computers. I think your workspace is setup in two different ways.

Comment: You path is not absolute, hence it will be resolved against the current working directory, which may differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be better to use relative path to guarantee cross-platform.

Usually, two ways to get resource:

1. getClass().getResourceAsStream()<**Non static method**> & xxx.Class.getResourceAsStream()<**static method**>
2. getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()<**Non static method**> & xxx.Class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()<**static method**>

What's the difference? 
[Please notice this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I24MN.png)

1. About #1, it use: 
   InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/json/rti.json");
2. For #2, it use: InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json/rti.json");

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on the Absolute path of a file for this very reason, it all depends on the location from which the other person is running the code.  In your case there is an additional MessageCompare directory.

Instead, use the class loader to load the file:

`MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myFile.txt");`

That way your code will be more portable.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
```

This line creates a file. The path of the file depends on your project folder and setup. If your workstation includes another folder inside named "MessageCompare" and your project is set up in that folder, that may be the reason you are getting an extra node.